# Wordpress: Custom font dont work

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

I have problem with custom font on my wordpress site, it works only on homepage but when you go on any subpages like http://domainname.com/about font stop work.

Kindly ask for some help.

Here is css which i use to pass fonts :

```
    @font-face {
font-family: 'TrajanPro-Bold';
src: url("wp-content/fonts/TrajanPro-Bold.otf");
src: url("wp-content/fonts/TrajanPro-Bold.otf?#iefix") format('opentype');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
font-family: 'AVENIRNEXT-BOLD';
src: url("wp-content/fonts/AVENIRNEXT-BOLD.OTF");
src: url("wp-content/fonts/AVENIRNEXT-BOLD.OTF?#iefix") format('opentype');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
font-family: 'AVENIRNEXT-ITALIC';
src: url("wp-content/fonts/avit.otf");
src: url("wp-content/fonts/avit.otf?#iefix") format('opentype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic; }

@font-face {
font-family: 'AVENIRNEXT-REGULAR';
src: url("wp-content/fonts/AVENIRNEXT-REGULAR.OTF");
src: url("wp-content/fonts/AVENIRNEXT-REGULAR.OTF?#iefix") format('opentype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }


@font-face {
font-family: 'JaneAust';
src: url("fonts/JaneAust.ttf");
src: url("wp-content/fonts/JaneAust.ttf?#iefix") format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Add a leading slash to your url("/wp-content...") ?

Comment: Oh my... stiupid me :) Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the URL `wp-content/fonts/TrajanPro-Bold.otf` will be relative to the current page directory.

Make the path absolute by adding a leading `slash /` to all the URLs.

Example: `/wp-content/fonts/TrajanPro-Bold.otf`

Comment: Yes ;) Like Eloims said above ,  i forgot about that :) just blindly copy/pasate from my old one-page project - Thank you so much for help :)